# Bound states with $E=m$ in relativistic Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

I have two basic questions:
**i)** **Is there a simple argument showing that there is no bound state with energy $E=m$ in the framework of relativistic Quantum Mechanics?**
I know that by the use of the dispersion relation $$E^{2}=p^{2}+m^{2},$$ this give us $p=0$, but I don't know if this is forbidden for bound states (if yes, we have the answer).
**ii) Is there some argument explaining that there are no bound states with energy in $[m,\infty)$, in the framework of relativistic Quantum Mechanics?**
There is no problem if you're able to fix only one of the two questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to the first question. The point is that the Hilbert space is separable by hypothesis.

Suppose $|m\rangle$ is a **proper** eigenvector of $P^0$. If $p= (m, \vec{0})$ and $\Lambda$ is a pure Lorentz transformation, one easily proves that  $U_\Lambda |m\rangle$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $|(\Lambda p)^0\rangle$. Since eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are orthogonal we have $\langle (\Lambda' p)^0 |(\Lambda p)^0\rangle =0$ if $\Lambda \neq \Lambda'$. Since $\Lambda$ continuously varies, the Hilbert space would contain a continuously infinite set of orthogonal vectors. This is is not possible since the Hilbert space of the system is supposed to be separable.